# jQuery burger menu issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a burger menu using jQuery but need your help to figure out the last couple bits. Firstly I have added a transition affect to the open menu link inside the nav which is not working. Secondly I need the #menu_list to close when the burger is closed. At the moment it remains open.

```
<div id="mobile_navBar">

  <div id="burger_icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>

  <ul>
    <img class="nav_decoration" src="images/top%20frame.png" alt="">
    <li id="open_menu"><a href="#">open menu</a></li>
    <ul id="menu_list">
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#welcomeAnchor">Welcome</a></li>
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#menuAnchor">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#timesAnchor">Opening Times</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img class="nav_decoration" src="images/Base%20Frame.png" alt="">
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

css:

```
#mobile_navBar{
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #111;
    position: relative;
    height: 4em;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#burger_icon{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#burger_icon span{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(1){
    top: 0;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(2), #burger_icon span:nth-child(3){
    top: 13px;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(4){
    bottom: 0px;
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(1){
    opacity: 0;
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(4){
    opacity: 0;
}

nav{
    margin-top: 4em; 
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

nav ul li{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li a{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

#menu_list{
    display: none;
    height: 0; 
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#menu_list.show{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}

#open_menu.hide{
    display: none;
}

#menu-list:nth-child(1){
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
    width: 55%;
}

#menu-list:nth-child(2){
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
    width: 55%;
}

nav.show{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.nav_decoration{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact_title{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact_title span{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
}

.mob_contact{
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.25em 0;
    display: block;
}

#mob_num{
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

#mob_icons{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#burger_icon, .auto_close").click(function() {

    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
    $("#burger_icon").toggleClass("open");

    $("#open_menu").click(function() {
      $("#menu_list").toggleClass("show");
      $("#open_menu").toggleClass("hide");
    });
  });
});
```

here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/Lsxht5bs/

Comment: your jsfiddle works fine, I can't se the problem, the burger menu opens and closes nicely

Comment: Works fine for me as well, please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough I will edit my post

Comment: Hopefully that is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Add below code inside click event of `$("#burger_icon, .auto_close")`.

`$("#menu_list").removeClass("show");`

`$("#open_menu").removeClass("hide");`

This will reset internal menu. And transition is working fine in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for solving my first problem. But as for the transition its not working fine. The transition for the burger works perfectly. But when you click the open menu link the list should transition like the main burger does

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the updated demo with your desired functionality with your updated code
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#burger_icon, .auto_close").click(function() {

    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
    $("#burger_icon").toggleClass("open");

    $("#open_menu").click(function() {
      $("#menu_list").toggleClass("show");
      $("#open_menu").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    
      if($('#menu_list').hasClass('show')) {
        $('#menu_list').removeClass('show');
        $("#open_menu").removeClass("hide");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#mobile_navBar{
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #111;
    position: relative;
    height: 4em;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#burger_icon{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#burger_icon span{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(1){
    top: 0;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(2), #burger_icon span:nth-child(3){
    top: 13px;
}

#burger_icon span:nth-child(4){
    bottom: 0px;
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(1){
    opacity: 0;
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#burger_icon.open span:nth-child(4){
    opacity: 0;
}

nav{
    margin-top: 4em; 
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

nav ul li{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li a{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

#menu_list{
    display: none;
    height: 0; 
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#menu_list.show{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}

#open_menu.hide{
    display: none;
}

#menu-list:nth-child(1){
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
    width: 55%;
}

#menu-list:nth-child(2){
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
    width: 55%;
}

nav.show{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.nav_decoration{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact_title{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact_title span{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #fff;
}

.mob_contact{
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.25em 0;
    display: block;
}

#mob_num{
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

#mob_icons{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile_navBar">

  <div id="burger_icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>

  <ul>
    <img class="nav_decoration" src="images/top%20frame.png" alt="">
    <li id="open_menu"><a href="#">open menu</a></li>
    <ul id="menu_list">
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#welcomeAnchor">Welcome</a></li>
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#menuAnchor">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="auto_close"><a href="#timesAnchor">Opening Times</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img class="nav_decoration" src="images/Base%20Frame.png" alt="">
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the if statement. Shouldn't the if statement remove the class as soon as it is added? I'm a little confused as to how this works

Comment: if statement works with conditions i just imposed a condition like this " if($('#menu_list').hasClass() " then do what you want inside the if body {} with in these brackets